# An equivalent representation of a convex compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Suppose a   convex compact  subset  $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ is the intersection of all closed halfspaces that contain it, then with the inner product and the standard norm $\|.\|_2$,

$$X=\bigcap_{f\in \mathbb R^n,   \|f\|_2\leq 1}  \{ x\in  \mathbb R^n :  \langle f, x\rangle\leq \sup_{x\in X}  \langle f,x\rangle\}$$

Since $f$ is used as a normal vector and only direction matters, can I replace $\|f\|_2\leq 1$ above equivalently by

$$\|f\|_{\infty}\leq 1$$

where $\|f\|_{\infty}=\max_{1\leq i\leq n} |f_i|$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is important to note that the set on the right-hand side (within the intersection) does not depend on the length of the vector $f$. And for every vector $f \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, you have
$$ \Bigg\| \frac{f}{\|f\|_2} \Bigg\|_2 = 1$$
and
$$ \Bigg\| \frac{f}{\|f\|_\infty} \Bigg\|_\infty = 1.$$